# How to handle ugly multideclarations (Code folding for non-method code)

Tags: java, formatting, codeblocks, declaration, folding

I havent found anything regarding my issue on this plattform, but forgive me if there should be something ive missed. My problem is quite simple: I have a really large block of FXML declarations due to my Scenebuilder and the block is very large and ugly. I want to fold it or to hide those declarations somewhere. Can somebody tell me how to collapse the code so i can flick it open if i want to?

Those declarations are all nescessary because each and every one of it has its own purpose. The scope needs to be quite large(like right beneath the class declaration) as i need those declarations for following methods.
Putting it in {} brackets would change the visibility...

EDIT: I do not get a specific error. It's rather about a better overview over the written code. My goal is to collapse this block of code like its commonly done with the bodies of methods. Im just not certain how to collapse code which is NOT in the body of a method.

```
 @FXML
Label labelA1, labelA2, labelA3, labelA4, labelA5, labelA6, 
labelA7, labelA8, labelA9, labelA10, labelA11, labelA12, labelA13, labelA14, labelA15, labelA16...
.
.
.
```

Comment: Hello, Welcome to SO. The community will be more helpful if you can describe in more detail as to what you are trying to achieve exactly and what is the specific error you are getting. This should help - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I helped myself...

You need to surround the block with the comment // at the top of the block and with  // at the bottom of it. Then you can collapse and extend the block in intellij. desc stands for the name that is shown when the block is collapsed.